# namenode not running... i have already tried sudo chown -R username /usr/local/hadoop/ please help

Tags: hadoop

```
$ /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh 
Starting namenodes on [localhost] 
divyeshlad@localhost's password:  
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-divyeshlad-namenode-divyeshlad-VirtualBox.out
localhost: chown: changing ownership of '/usr/local/hadoop/logs': Operation not permitted
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-divyeshlad-namenode-divyeshlad-VirtualBox.out: Permission denied
localhost: head: cannot open '/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-divyeshlad-namenode-divyeshlad-VirtualBox.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-divyeshlad-namenode-divyeshlad-VirtualBox.out: Permission denied
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-divyeshlad-namenode-divyeshlad-VirtualBox.out: Permission denied
```

Comment: thanks @Thomas  that helped i logged in as chown -R divyeshlad /usr/local/hadoop and namenode is now running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first the script tells you that it is deprecated and you should use the scripts `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`.

Second, you are starting the services as user `divyeshlad`, who does not have write permissions in `/usr/local/hadoop/logs`.

So either start the services as `root` or `chown -R divyeshlad /usr/local/hadoop/logs`.
Not sure if the latter one will work as I do not know if Hadoop needs `root` rights for running.